# Trigger Jenkins build using slack (Jenkins hosted in enterprise server without internet)

Tags: jenkins, slack

How can I use Slack trigger a Jenkins build for which Jenkins is hosted in a enterprise server without Internet connectivity?

I tried slash command in Slack, but when slack is trying to reach the Jenkins URL error is returned since its not accessible in internet.

Comment: This is not possibile as slack works on public . Have a look
https://api.slack.com/events-api#receiving_events